# How to save all modified buffers and kill emacs

Tags: functions

I use the well known key-binding <kbd>C-x C-c</kbd> to quit emacs. However this command asks y/n confirmation to save modified buffers and if there are process buffers (eg. Shell) it also asks for yes/no confirmation before to exit.

I'd like a command that save all modified buffers, then kill emacs. Is there any function that does do this?

Answer (score 8):

From the docstring of `C-x C-c`:

> With prefix ARG, silently save all file-visiting buffers, then kill.

So you want to use `C-u C-x C-c`

**EDIT:** If you also want that the above silently kills all running processes, then you can set the variable `confirm-kill-processes` to nil.

Comment: This is no really what I need, because It still asks yes/no confirmation for "active processes", like shell, R or whatever.

Comment: Ok emacs asks you "Active processes exist; kill them and exit anyway?" Pressing 'y' should kill the active proceses altogether. Is it not the case for you or is it this one additional key that you want to avoid?

Comment: If you wish to *always* kill active processes without prompting, then customize the user option `confirm-kill-processes`.

Comment: Thanks @phils I have included your hint in the answer

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved this with the following

```
;; [M-x  my-quit] and [C-c q] 
;; save all buffers then shuts down  emacs stopping all current processes 
(defun my-quit ()
  (interactive)
  (save-some-buffers t)
  (kill-emacs))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c q")  'my-quit)
```

I bind the function to C-c q which I don't use, but you can bind the command to whatever you like.

Comment: I strongly recommend against rebinding `C-q`.  `quoted-insert` is fairly crucial in situations where there's no easy way of typing certain characters (a classic example being `C-q C-j` to type a newline at a prompt where RET would just submit the input).

Comment: Every `C-c <letter>` sequence (for both upper- and lower-case letters) is reserved for end-users to bind, so you can safely use `C-c q`

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I edited the solution above and I set <kbd>C-c q<kbd> in my .emacs file. Thanks a lot!